# Does Google Audio Player gadget for Google Sites have a new URL?

Tags: google-sites, google-reader

My Google Sound website relies on using Google Audio Player gadget which was hosted on a Google Reader URL ("http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf").

However, along with Google Reader, this player also appears to have been killed (perhaps inadvertently). This means that no sound can be played from my Google Sites website anymore.

Does anyone know whether it has been moved somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

problem solution https://sites.google.com/site/mori79/html-gadgets/media-players/google-reader-player/audio-player.zip or http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp have good sound